# Sorting by preferred average value

Tags: mysql, sorting

I'm making a game that involves people downloading and rating user-created maps. They have the option to upvote/downvote the map if they like/dislike it, as well as rate its difficult on a scale of 1-10.

In the map browser, they have the option to sort maps by highest rated. This is done using [Laplace smoothing](http://planspace.org/2014/08/17/how-to-sort-by-average-rating/) so that it factors both the number of upvotes as well as the total number of ratings into the sorting, sorting by `(upvotes + 1)/(numRatings + 2)`. This works fine.

Now, there's also an option to sort by preferred difficulty, where people can choose a value from 1-10, and it will sort maps by how close the average difficulty rating is to the preferred rating. At first I was sorting by `ABS(preferred_difficulty - average_difficulty)`, but that didn't factor in the number of ratings. Right now I'm using `((numRatings + 1) * (10 - ABS(average_difficulty - preferred_difficulty)) + 1) / (numRatings + 1.5)` out of sheer trial and error, which kinda works, but sometimes the number of ratings outweighs the preferred difficulty and the results look strange.

This is what I need help with - I can't figure out how to sort by smallest difference between preferred and average difficulty while incorporating number of ratings into the mix, since I want a low difficulty delta with a high rating count to be the best result instead of a high upvote count with a high rating count, like it is with the ratings.

For example, if this is the data:

```
AvgDifficulty      NumRatings
      6.0                 1
      4.0                25
      6.8                 4
      6.2                 3
      6.5                20
      6.2                 1
      6.4                 3
```

And someone chooses a preferred difficulty of 6.4, I'd want it to sort something like this:

```
AvgDifficulty      NumRatings
      6.5                20 
      6.4                 3   
      6.2                 3
      6.8                 4
      6.2                 1  
      6.0                 1
      4.0                25
```

Basically I want results that are close to the preferred difficulty at the top, but I'd rather show results that are 0.1 off with lots of ratings over exact matches with very few ratings. I understand getting "right" results may not be very concrete in this case, I'm just looking for a starting point.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results (in a table structure in the question).  It is easy to misunderstand such a long explanation without examples.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bit of a nebulous question.  You need some way to combine the rating and the count.  The basic query is:

```
order by abs(avg_difficulty - 6.4)
```

But, you want to include the count as well.  You can define a fixed band at the top and order these by the ranking:

```
order by (case when abs(avg_difficulty - 6.4) < 0.1) then numratings end) desc,
         abs(avg_difficulty - 6.4)
```

This expression combines everything from 6.3 - 6.5 in one group and sorts these by the number of ratings.  The second key sorts everything else by the difference.